# How to implement Python import libraries on Xampp localhost?

Tags: python, php, apache, xampp

I'm trying to implement running machine learning on my web.
I set my Xampp addhandler .py so that can handle python files.
Basically, I checked everything python works on my web.
But the problem is that cannot import any libraries such as cv2, easyocr, and imutils.

```
#!C:\Users\parkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
print("Content-type: text/html\n")
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
import easyocr
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

print("Hello World")
```

And this is my result page,
[result page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfyS7.jpg)
Nothing shows.
So, what I doubt is that it can't load libraries from localhost.
Because if I set the code like,

```
#!C:\Users\parkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
print("Content-type: text/html\n")
print("Hello World")
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
import easyocr
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Then, it prints Hello World very well!
I'm googling for 2 days to solve this problem. But totally cannot get what's the problem.
Is it not possible to use package libraries on web?
My web server is Apache Xampp.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to read this, it will help you a lot I think:
[the article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-easily-run-python-visualizations-on-a-web-browser-with-pyscript-4b287ef991cd)

“How to Easily Run Python Visualizations On a Web Browser with PyScript”